# Configuring virtual hosts in apache2

Tags: apache2

I'm using Apache 2.4.7 and trying to configure virtual hosts.

I'm getting:

```
You don't have permission to access ... on this server
```

error when I'm using following configuration:

```
ScriptAlias /WD190AWP/ "/usr/local/WebDev/19.0/AWP/"
<directory "/usr/local/WebDev/19.0/AWP/">  
    allow from all
    order allow,deny
</directory>
```

If I change "**order allow, deny**" by "**Require all granted**",

```
ScriptAlias /WD190AWP/ "/usr/local/WebDev/19.0/AWP/"
<directory "/usr/local/WebDev/19.0/AWP/">  
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</directory>
```

Then I get following error:

```
The requested URL ... was not found on this server
```

What could be wrong?
Thanks;
Gus

Comment: First, that is not a virtual host, you are configuring access. Second it could be any number of problems. - "The requested URL ... was not found on this server" and what URL is that ? You need to also check the apache logs.

Comment: The point here is that changing the permissions (order allow,deny by Require all granted) makes the server response from "don't have permissions (admitting that the directory exists)" to "it doesn't exist". So it's a configuration problem, but I don't know how to solve it.